# C# ProtectedMemory и Task - насколько безопасно

Tags: c#

Возник вопрос, насколько безопасно использовать [ProtectedMemory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection) в Task'ах с одной статистической переменной?

Эксперименты на коленке не выявили проблем вроде, пробовал на модели Singleton. На msdn тоже вразумительно поведение в подобных ситуациях не описано.

Поделитесь соображениями, Локи надо выставлять самостоятельно на этих операциях или не обязательно.

Comment: Судя по МСДН - вся работа сводится к изменению массива. Т.е. пока вы не пытаетесь одновременно работать с массивом мешая самому себе - апи вполне поддерживает работу в тасках.

Comment: В том то и вопрос, при изменении массива оно внутри ставит лок или нет, вероятность его изменения в несколько лиц довольно высока :)

Comment: Без явного описания - лучше рассчитывать что лока нет. Ну и, можно потестировать.

Comment: Пробовал, вроде работает, но не факт что на локальных тестах можно гарантированно достичь точки пересечения. В общем наверно остановлюсь на установке собственного лока, хоть это и снижает мультипоточную юзабельность.